# Переход на с# под веб: классический asp или core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Решил перейти с PHP на C# для работы под веб. Как я понял, есть 2 актуальных фрейморка, для перехода: .NET MVC5 и .NET Core 2.

Так вот вопрос, расскажите пожалуйста, с чего будет лучше начинать, какие преимущества у данной технологии, отличия и т.п. Мне нужен будет, для написание высоконагруженного проекта в дальнейшем.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нужно понимать, что .NET Core != ASP.NET Core.

.NET Core - это кросплатформенный фреймворк. Для разработки различных видов приложений, от консолек до микросервисов

---

ASP.NET Core - это фреймворк для разработки Web-приложений, который может работать как на .NET Core, так и на обычном .NET Framework. Core в названии - это просто странный маркетинговый трюк.

Вот так выглядит wizard создания проекта ASP.NET Core, если вызывать его из поддерева Web, а не из поддерева Core. Вы можете вполне выбрать полный .NET Framework.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сравнению с ASP.NET MVC 5, ASP.NET Core - это просто следующая версия. 
ASP.NET MVC 5 вышел в 2013-ом году. После этого он был значительно переработан, получил поддержку .NET Core, и следующая его версия была выпущена под именем ASP.NET Core.

Это просто особенность нумерации версий ASP.NET - 1, 2, 3, 4, (5),  Core 1, Core 2.

Так что ваш вопрос на самом деле сводится к "учить версию 5 пятилетней давности или учить последнюю версию 5 + 2". Ответ, на мой взгляд, очевиден :)

Comment: Справедливости ради, `ASP.NET Core` был переписан с нуля, по новым архитектурным принципам: свой DI контейнер, Middleware, общий класс контроллера для API & Web app, убрали всякое старье типа Web Forms и много еще чего. Из общего там остался только Razor View и часть названия `ASP.NET`.

Comment: @Bulson это же не единомоментно произошло в виде релиза ASP.NET Core :) Middleware пришли из owin / katana (примерно 2012-й год), и они работали (и частично, работают) в обычном не-core ASP.NET 4. Классы API контроллера пристыковались из WCF Data Services, и в Core просто воспользовались возможностью поломать обратную совместимость и слить с MVC. Web Forms движок дропнули по умолчанию в конфиге где-то во времена ASP.NET MVC 3/4. Поддержка DI добавилась в ASP.NET MVC 4 (2013 год примерно), Core добавил только реализацию контейнера по умолчанию.

Comment: @Bulson т.е. это эволюционный процесс, но ощущается как резкое "все с нуля переписали" из-за необходимости сразу подхватить пачку новшеств, многие из которых могли пройти мимо за последние 4-5 лет.

Answer (score 6):

В октябре 2018 заканчивается [срок техподдержки asp.net core 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/support/policy) поэтому пишите сразу на asp.net core 2.1 -- технология эта уже давно зрелая, можно использовать в продакшене.

В её же достоинствах - мультиплатформенность, сможете запускать не только на IIS под windows, но и на линкс-платформах, где-нибудь в облаке. Я вот пишу код и тестирую на windows 10 -- но продакшн у меня на линуксе.

Что до остального... во-первых, я мало видел тех, кому реально был нужен высоконагруженный хайлоад, так что и на ваш проект смотрю скептически, с таким-то уровнем вопроса. Не, вот без обид: где в вопросе конкретные цифры нагрузки хотя бы?

И да, вопрос нужно перефразировать, чтобы можно было дать какой-то определённый ответ. С чего нужно начинать -- это больше вопрос нечёткого выбора, у каждого свои вводные, тут не угадать.

Comment: Кстати о зрелости. M$ переписала и запустила свой поисковичек Bing на .net core 2.1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/20/bing-com-runs-on-net-core-2-1/

Comment: @Bulson Это не совсем зрелось. Золотых партнёров тоже заставляют софт переписывать под новые платформы, я на себе это хорошо знаю. Думаю, тут больше маркетинга. А вот срок окончания техподдержки 2.0 для меня  стал важным звоночком.

Comment: Маркетинг, это да, но с другой стороны, если бы они не были уверены в этой своей новинке не стали бы рисковать таким ресурсом как Bing.

Comment: Можно подумать что откатить предыдущий движок Бинга это сложно :) лежит, наверняка, в сторонке, ждёт когда новая поделка сломается :)